# How to read the definition of Grothendieck Pretopology in SGA4?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory, grothendieck-topology

In SGA4, the first axiom of a Grothendieck pretopology is given as:

> PT0: Pour tout objet $X$ de $C$, les morphismes des familles de morphismes de $Cov()$
> sont quarrables. (Rappelons qu’un morphisme $Y \to X$  est dit quarrable si pour
> tout morphisme $Z \to X$ le produit fibré $Z \times_X Y$  est représentable).

[A translation](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10485-023-09722-3.pdf?pdf=button#myseccnt.2) of this is :

> If $\{U_i \to U \}$ is a covering and $f : V \to U$ any morphism, then all $U_i ×_U V$ exist.

I'm wondering how the quantifiers are to be parsed in this. There's two ways I can see reading this axiom:

1. For each morphism $g_i : U_i \to U $ in a covering family $F \in Cov(U)$, and for each $f : V \to U$, the pullback of $g_i$ and $f$ exists
2. For every covering family $F \in Cov(U)$ and morphism $f : V \to U$, there is a pullback between $f$ and $F$, i.e. a single fiber-product of $f$ and *all* $(f_i : U_i \to U) \in F$

i.e. Is there a pullback for each morphism in a covering family, or is there one pullback for the whole family?

(1) seems to go against my intuition for covering: the entire family taken together covers $U$, so why should a single morphism in the family have to have a pullback with an arbitrary morphism?

But (2) leaves me unclear about what it means to have a pullback between a morphism and a whole family of morphisms.

Which is the intended reading of the definition? Is there a reference that spells this out explicitly? I've had trouble, since most references assume you're working in a category with all pullbacks and hence don't need this axiom.

Comment: It seems to me that it says "the morphisms in the family of morphisms are squarable".  That is, it is stating a condition on morphisms, which is required to apply for each morphism in a family, rather than stating a condition directly on families of morphisms.  That would be reading (1).  As to whether it fits with the intuition or the intention, I couldn't say.

Comment: It is the first one. The French text has no ambiguity (it defines that a map is *quarrable* if the pullback exists along any "base change", and the condition is that every map in every covering family is quarrable). This is also the definition in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03NH

Comment: Without looking at SGA4, I think the point is that there should be another axiom saying that the induced family $\{U_i\times_U V\to V\}$ is a covering of $V$ but you first need this family to exist.

Comment: In other words you shouldn't necessarily try to isolate the intuitive meaning of a single part of a definition outside the context of the whole.